# Rails map.root problem redirecting to incorrect URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that is deployed on a machine but not to the root of that machine using Passenger (i.e. RailsBaseURI /myapp).  I've tried to set up map.root to point to one of my controllers in the routes:

map.root :controller => :target

and it's redirecting, but not to the right place.  Instead of going to www.mymachine.com/myapp/target, it's going to www.mymachine.com/target, which is not correct.  I'm not sure what I'm missing, but it seems like it must be something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can set ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = 'myapp' in your configuration.

Also, you can use map.root :controller => :target, :path_prefix => 'myapp'

The later approach need to be done for each resource, while the first one applies to all!